# Create a Sharepoint Site through Powershell Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft

I'm learning about creating a Sharepoint/Modern Site using Rest API and powershell, created the code but unfortunately without any luck. As a result I have this error, I guess I need some additional permissions/rights?

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}
At line:44 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $jso ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Please find the code below I'm trying:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential  
$SiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/SPSiteManager/create"  
$headers = @{
    "Accept" = "application/json;odata.metadata=none"
}
$Body = @"
                    {
    "Title": "Communication Site 1",
    "Url":"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/commsite1",
    "Lcid": 1033,
    "ShareByEmailEnabled":false,
    "Classification":"Low Business Impact",
    "SensitivityLabel": "None",
    "Description":"Description",
    "WebTemplate":"SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
    "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
    "Owner":"owner@sharepoint.com",
    "WebTemplateExtensionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                      }
"@
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $SiteUrl -Credential $Cred -Headers $headers -Body $Body
```

Thanks!

================================================================
Update: Working Script

```
Import-Module MSAL.PS

#Variables
$ClientID = "XXX"
$ClientSecret = "XXX"
$ClientCertificate = Get-Item "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\XXX"
$tenantID = "XXX"
$scope = "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/.default"
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$Body = @{
  "grant_type"    = "client_credentials";
  "client_id"     = "$ClientID";
  "client_secret" = "$ClientSecret";
  "scope"      = "$scope";
}

#Get AccessToken
#$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri $authority -Body $body
#$AccessToken = $result.access_token

#Get AccessToken with MSAL
$AccessToken = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $ClientID -TenantId $tenantID -ClientCertificate $ClientCertificate -Scope $scope
# Inspect the Access Token using JWTDetails PowerShell Module
$AccessToken.AccessToken | Get-JWTDetails

#Create Event
$headers = @{
# "Authorization" = "Bearer "+ $AccessToken;
# "Authorization" = $AccessToken.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
# "Authorization" = "Bearer "+ $AccessToken.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
 "Authorization" = "Bearer $($AccessToken.AccessToken)";
 "Accept" = "application/json;odata.metadata=none";
 "Content-Type" = "application/json;odata=verbose";
 "odata-version" = "4.0"
}

#Create JSON Object
$json = @"
{
  "request": {
    "Title": "Communication Site 1",
    "Url":"https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/commsite1",
    "Lcid": 1033,
    "ShareByEmailEnabled":false,
    "Classification":"Low Business Impact",
    "Description":"Description",
    "WebTemplate":"SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
    "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
    "Owner":"XXX@XXX.com",
    "WebTemplateExtensionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
}
"@

$uri = "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/_api/SPSiteManager/create"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $json
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using, SharePoint online? If yes, you can create a site using PnP PowerShell or [Power automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/29/create-a-sharepoint-online-site-using-power-automate-flow/) more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Sharepoint online. I've seen the ways to do it via PnP Powershell and Power Automate, however I need it via Rest API, as our developers will have to automate the Sharepoint Site creation from another service/system (HCL Domino, it will be done via json)

Comment: Find out how the developers plan to obtain an access token, and do that in your Powershell. But jeez, if all you need to do is prove out the concept, you can just use Postman

Comment: Thanks @DerekGusoff for the hint with access token. I've just tried with an access token (with client/tenant id/secret) and got Unsupported code for Sharepoint API. Doing some more research found out that we need to do it with a certificate as well, so I'll work on it further to see if I'll manage to get the access token :)

Comment: I'm assessing the options for a project, thus I'm kind of the person who needs to find out what would the options to do it. I already did an alternative of creating Teams Site via MS graph (same with client/tenant ID/secret ), with MS 365 group which creates by default a site and then also with Graph you can create/update pages on the site etc. But I need to see how Communication sites can be created (how to create new pages, update them etc.), and for this Sharepoint Rest API are needed

Comment: Solved. Updated first post with the right script